# What weather conditions would lead to lightning strikes before sunrise?

Tags: mountaineering, weather, lightning

Twice now I have been summitting peaks in Rocky Mountain National Park while getting really early starts to avoid the afternoon thunderstorms.

However in both cases I could still see lighting in the distance several hours before sunrise (think 3:30 to 6:00 am).

What type of weather conditions would lead to lightning strikes before sunrise?

Comment: Thunderstorms can last a long time. Further south in New Mexico were I live, we often get thunderstorms coming over the foothills into the Rio Grande valley in the early morning hours, midnight to 4am. Occasionally there are early morning storms, mostly in the valley.

Answer (score 2):

Thunderstorms due to diurnal variations from the previous day that still last as well as incoming cold fronts could be the cause. The former wouldn't be a big threat, as they would abate, the latter would likely thwart any attempt at the peak (however generally you would be aware of it due to forecasting).

Comment: I did not take into account anything specific to the Rockies, as I know nothing about it, but I assume this should be applicable generally. If there's something more applicable that's Rocky-specific, I am sure someone will bring it up.